# Method didSelectAnnotation does not work (Skobbler iOS)

Tags: ios, skmaps

This problem appeared after an update to the latest Skobbler version. 
When I try to select any annotation, only this method get's called

```
-(void)mapView:(SKMapView *)mapView 
    didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
```

But not `didSelectAnnotation`.

After zooming the
`didSelectAnnotation` method works fine.

Anyone knows what's happening?

Comment: DidTapAtCoordinate shows that you've clicked somewhere on the map, didSelectAnnotation shows that you've clicked on an annotation. DidTapAtCoordinate will not be triggered if didSelectAnnotation is triggered. Could you detail what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: I want to select any annotation from any zoom level. Now it happens only when I'm zooming closely to location. But method didTapAtCoordinate is triggered as you can see.

Comment: So, you're clicking on an annotation and didSelectAnnotation is not triggered? (but didTapAtCoordinate is?)

Comment: Yes, you are right. But on different zoom levels didSelectAnnotation is triggered. I don't understand why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is simple. I've just set

> annotationTapZoomLimit = 0

in map's settings.

Thanks for attention.