# SKMapview didselectannotation method not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

hi i had added and created a skmapview and delegate methods in a viewcontroller called mapviewcontroller and added it as a sub view in another viewcontroller. the view loads correctly but when i try to select an annotation, the didselectannotaion method is not called in the map viewcontroller.i had also tried to set delegate to mapview viewcontroller but nothing happened. please advice how to make the map delegate methos working

```
- (IBAction)btn_Map:(id)sender
{
MapViewController *map=[[ViewController alloc]init];
sample = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapVC"];
sample.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view_map.bounds.size.width, self.view_map.bounds.size.height);
[self.mapView addSubview:map.view];
}
```

Comment: Isn't this line wrong MapViewController *map=[[ViewController alloc]init]; ?IT should be MapViewController *map=[[MapViewController alloc]init]; Also you are not using the sample instance.

Comment: You should check first if the issue is not the one mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972096/method-didselectannotation-does-not-work-skobbler-ios

Comment: Like Sylvia mentioned check your tabZoomLimit setting as this can explain the behaviour you are experiencing

Comment: thanks a lot it worked....@SylviA